# Show starred questions tab in search results page

Tags: feature-request, search

When I do a search for something, usually I want to find a specific question I have previously been to. If I am searching for it, it is likely to have been considered important and starred. I would like an extra tab alongside "info", "newest", "frequent", "votes", "active" and "unanswered", labelled "starred" that only shows questions I have starred that match my search criteria.

**Edit:** Both answers thus far have commented that there is an `infavourites:mine` filter that can be applied to the results. Given that I've been here many years and did not know of this, an alternative way of satisfying this feature request would be to place a link on the search results page which appends this filter to the query string.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a "starred" filter switch somewhere in the screen so that you can see your starred questions _among_ the newest, frequent, votes, etc. search results.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark particular question as favourite and then return as and when you desire.. Once you starred as favourite you can visit those question in your profile --> favorites tab

> [image]

If you have many favourites question make use of Advance search tip... like `infavorites:mine searchData`

Comment: But if you star more than just a few questions, you need use the search functionality within them, which is what the question is about.

Comment: you can take help of Advance search tips for that matter like `infavorites:mine searchData`

Answer (score 2):

We really do not require an additional tab for starred questions in the search result because [we can search within our favorites questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+select+infavorites%3A1369235) or [other user's favorites questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc#%5D%20infavorites:22656).